# AngularJs directive, show template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have divs, which generates dynamically, based on server data. All this divs have their `keyboard` values: `numpad` or `fullkeyboard` (based on server data).
For example:

```
[
    {
        label: 'NICK NAME',
        keyboard: 'fullKeyboard'
    },
    {
        label: 'AGE',
        keyboard: 'numpad'
    }
]
```

And I have templates, for both keyboard.

I want that, when user clicks on those divs, display correct key-board template.

How it is possible to do?

MY HTML:

```
<div id="container-of-inputDivs">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, item) in dataSource" data-keyboard="item.keyboard"></div>
</div>



<keyboard />
```

Comment: Can you please show your view, e.g. the html part?

Comment: Thx. What does `<keyboard />` do? Is it a directive?

Comment: yes. It will be directive, where will be load keyboard templates. 
I don't know if I'm doing right. I'm beginner in angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your keyboard directive must have some scope attribute, like so:

```
<div keyboard="activeKeyboard"></div>
```

Then, your divs could look like this (assuming that `dataSource` is the array you provided in the question):

```
<div id="container-of-inputDivs">
    <div ng-repeat="item in dataSource" ng-click="activeKeyboard=item">
</div>
```

This way, when you click on the div, the `activeKeyboard` gets set to `item`, which is stored inside the variable `activeKeyboard` on the scope.

From your directive, you can return something like this:

```
{
  template: 'your-template-here',
  scope: {
    keyboard: '='
  },
  ...
}
```

You isolate the scope with two-way-binding . You could now use the isolated keyboard object inside your template.

**EDIT:**
EXAMPLES ON HOW TO USE IT

There are many ways to go from here. Here are two examples:

1) With dynamic code inside template

```
{
  template: '<div>{{keyboard.label}}</div>',
  scope: {
    keyboard: '='
  },
  ...
}
```

2) Different templates based on scope

Suppose you have two different templates you want to include, based on your keyboard's scope: `/templates/fullKeyboard.html` and `/templates/numpad.html`.

```
{
  template: '<div ng-include="getTemplateUrl()"></div>',
  scope: {
    keyboard: '='
  },
  controller: function($scope) {
    $scope.getTemplateUrl = function() {
      return '/templates/' + $scope.keyboard.keyboard + '.html';
    }
  }
}
```

As I said, there are many ways of doing it, depends on your architecture and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you. 

But I have now error: 

`Multiple directives [keyboard (module: SPS.Directives), keyboard (module: SPS.Directives)] asking for new/isolated on: {5}`

Comment: I think it is because you use `keyboard` twice, as a directive name and as variable name. I updated my answer...

Comment: now there is not error.

But, I can't understand how to change template's url, on div's click

Answer (score 1):

You could use ng-include and then have a function returning the correct html template depending on the keyboard variable.

ex:

```
vm.GetKeyboardTemplate = function(keyboard){return keyboard + ".html";}

<div ng-include="{{vm.GetKeyboardTemplate(item.keyboard);}}"></div>
```